# Paginate is limiting my csv export using Comma gem - how to work around?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, csv, render

Here is the relevant code:

```
def index
    @customer = Customer.new
    if(session[:admin_id])
      @allJobs = Job.where(:merchant_id => session[:admin_id].to_s).paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
    else
      @allJobs = Job.all(:order => :_id.desc).paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
    end
    respond_to do |format|      
      #@allJobs = Job.where(:merchant_id => session[:admin_id].to_s)
      format.html
      #format.csv {send_data to_csv(@all_customers)}
      format.csv { render :csv => @allJobs }
```

When I click export - I get a csv of @allJobs... for just the 15 items displayed.

As you can see, in the format block I tried to redefine @allJobs to just everything with the merchant_id, but that throws an error:

```
No comma format for class Plucky::Query defined for style {}
```

I tried changing the var name to something else - same error.  I just want to export all the jobs that match the merchant_id statement.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone lands here after googling comma errors like these:

- `No comma format for class String defined for style {}`
- `No comma format for class TrueClass defined for style {}`

Then check to make sure you're not abusing the `.to_comma` method. You do not need to call this method in your rails controller.

**Incorrect**:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { render :csv => @things.to_comma}
end
```

**Correct**:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { render :csv => @things}
end
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of working around pagination's limit for particular request types, such as CSV for an export, uses controller checking the request object before calling paginate. For example:

```
def index
    @customer = Customer.new
    if(session[:admin_id])
      @allJobs = Job.where(:merchant_id => session[:admin_id].to_s)
      unless  request.format == "csv"
        @allJobs= @allJobs.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
      end
    else
      if  request.format == "csv"
        @allJobs = Job.all(:order => :_id.desc)
      else
         @allJobs = Job.all(:order => :_id.desc).paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])

      end
    end
    respond_to do |format|      
      #@allJobs = Job.where(:merchant_id => session[:admin_id].to_s)
      format.html
      #format.csv {send_data to_csv(@all_customers)}
      format.csv { render :csv => @allJobs }
```

Note that the :admin_id case, we can chain the pagnation method while in the non admin_id case the .all method returns an array that we can't call paginate on.

Comment: This is very useful answer  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this works, but:

```
format.csv { render :csv => @allJobs.paginate }
```

Just adding .paginate without calling any options made this export all Jobs regardless of the 15 displayed per page.

Full updated code:

```
def index
    @customer = Customer.new
    if(session[:admin_id])
      @allJobs = Job.where(:merchant_id => session[:admin_id]
    else
      @allJobs = Job.all(:order => :_id.desc).paginate(:per_page => 50, :page => params[:page])
    end
    respond_to do |format|      
      #@allJobs = Job.where(:merchant_id => session[:admin_id].to_s)
      format.html do
        @allJobs = @allJobs.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
      end
      format.csv { render :csv => @allJobs.paginate }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solution and couldnt get it to work.  In the end, which I am sure is not optimal, I generated another instance variable without the pagination and called that for the export.  Example code below

```
...    
@allJobs = Job.all(:order => :_id.desc).paginate(:per_page => 50, :page => params[:page])
@allJobs_xls = Job.all(:order => :_id.desc)
```